# How do I destroy the Tiamat?

Tags: freespace-2

In the mission "Proving Grounds" of Freespace 2's base campaign, there's this one middle-class enemy ship that flies in, designation "Tiamat". And, well...**it's a pain to destroy**. The game insists that I have to stay within scanning range of the ship in order for my allied ship to fire its lasers at the Tiamat, but on one test run I spent the entire mission inside this nice little cove where one of its subsystems was conveniently located firing torpedos into its hull. If that's not proximity, I don't know what is.

Here's a diagram representing my woes:

```
ALLIED SHIP              TIAMAT (NOT DEAD)
________
|      |===============\________________________
|      |===============/|                      |
|      |                | __                   |
|______|                | |_| ME (practically  |
                        |________inside ship)__|
```

Is there some kind of trick I'm missing here or something? How do I destroy the Tiamat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Once the second part of the test is
>   about to begin, a group of Shivan
>   fighters (Mara) will jump in ... time
>   for some real action. A bit later the
>   Taurus group will jump in. These are
>   bombers, so intercept them and their
>   bombs first! They pose a serious
>   threat to the Aquitaine. By the time
>   you have taken them out a corvette
>   will jump in (Tiamat) ... destroy it
>   first! Target the beam turrets, so it
>   doesn't inflict much damage to the
>   Aquitaine. Then go for whichever
>   weapon system you want ... I usually
>   go for the flaks or missile launchers
>   first, but tend to pick off a laser
>   here and there as the opportunity
>   arises. Remember that you have to keep
>   close to the Tiamat in order to get
>   help from the Aquitaine. Your sensors
>   allow the Aquitaine to open fire. Once
>   the Tiamat is destroyed (or jumped
>   out) take care off the remaining
>   fighters.

[Source](http://www.the-spoiler.com/ACTION/Volition/freespace.2.1/missions/2125.htm)

I don't think you're supposed to be *in* it. Just keep a close range. Either way, you don't get the "Order of Galatea" medal for destroying the Tiamat, you get it for keeping Aquitaine's hull above 51%, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't destroy the Tiamat on your own. You do not have any weapons that have the "Huge" flag in the mission, which are required to damage ships above Cruiser size beyond a certain hull damage (can't remember the threshold).

To destroy the Tiamat, you need the Aquitaine to do so with its anti capship beams or huge (blob) turrets.